# How to test if result of "pipe" operations are "undefined" . TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

Tags: angular, observable

I made some operations in an observable withe rxjs operator "pipe". The app works but when I run test I have this error : "TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined"

I also tried to use filter operator to skip undefined value of observable.
I also tried to make a function when I put operations of "pipe" operator to test his return. After that I subscribe on it but I have the same error

```
this.repertory.family
                  .pipe(
                    map(d => d.map(dr => dr.name).reduce((prev, curr) => prev.concat(curr), [])),
                  )
                  .subscribe(d=> (this.person= d.find(character=> (character.id= this.zoning.ref))))
```

I want to test if the result of "pipe" operator operations are "undefined".
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Add a filter

```
this.repertory.family.pipe(
  map(d => d.map(dr => dr.name).reduce((prev, curr) => prev.concat(curr), [])),
  filter(Boolean),
).subscribe(
  d=> (this.person= d.find(character=> (character.id= this.zoning.ref)))
)
```

Comment: thank you for your help but now I have an error on "find" operator ( into the subscribe)  : Property 'find' does not exist on type 'unknown'.ts(2339)

Comment: And why exactly is it downvoted? With the filter the error won't occur, since subscription isn't triggered.